# Pandas: Multiple values for the same timestamp, how to plot it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to deal with a vibration dataset which contains multiple y-axis values for a day. Indeed, these values are only from 3 seconds in the day inside a list of integers.

I have N sensors with each sensor a list of integers [4321, 2134, 541,..., 1234] representing vibrations during 3 seconds in one day.
So far I have a DataFrame with N sensors for each day and with a list of ints in the Vibration col. All the lists should have the same amount of elements in this 3 seconds.

What I would like is a way to plot a graph with timestamp vs vibration and, moreover, the color being the sensor. So, at the end of the day, a typical plot confronting all the sensor data.

The dataset is sth like:

> Sensor  |  Timestamp    |    Vibration

> A977549 | 2022-02-28 |    [4101, 4028, 3290, 3419, 2...]
>
> A977549 | 2022-02-27 |    [3518, 3457, 6234, 331, 1...]

> B977549 | 2022-02-28 |    [3798, 6417, 234, 331, 3...]

> B977549 | 2022-02-27 |    [3591, 2417, 434, 3341, 2...]

...

It is always sampled at the same time in day, or at least we can assume it, during this 3 seconds mentioned.

Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: Is vibration a list of measurements taken along the day? If so, you could use `explode` and add a `Time` column (given you know at what time the measures took place) that you could combine with `Timestamp` (actually Date) to get Datetime (your x-axis).

Comment: No, the vibration measurements are only from 3 seconds in one day. I only have this 3 seconds of data for each day. It seems to me the only way to plot it would be upsampling the data but ending up with non-real one, which may cause my troubles later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I could completely make sense of your question but as far as I understood, you want multiple lines for a single sensor (for each position in the list).

You could create new columns from your lists and build one plot per sensor:

```py
columns = ['Sensor', 'Timestamp', 'Vibration']
data = [['A977549', '2022-02-28', [4101, 4028, 3290, 3419]],
['A977549', '2022-02-27', [3598, 3417, 4234, 3341]],
['B977549', '2022-02-28', [4101, 4028, 3290, 3419]],
['B977549', '2022-02-27', [3598, 3417, 4234, 3341]]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])

df_vibr = pd.DataFrame(df['Vibration'].to_list(), columns=[f'Vibr_{i}' for i in range(len(df.loc[0, 'Vibration']))])

df = df.join(df_vibr).drop('Vibration', axis=1)
#print(df)

for sensor, subdf in df.groupby('Sensor'):
    subdf.plot(x='Timestamp', y=df.columns[2:], xticks=df['Timestamp'].to_list(), title=sensor)

plt.show()
```

With an added sensor to your example I get following graphs:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay let me first of all appreciate your time but I think we are not understanding each other. Again, I will try to expose the problem modifying the original question.